# Не работают Google Play Games Services

Tags: unity3d, google-play-services

Здравствуйте, делаю игру на unity, и вот появилась задача реализации таблицы лидеров, решил использовать google play games, так как есть аккаунт разработчика, испортировал плагин, сделал скрипт авторизации как описано на странице github, но таблица не показывается, и авторизация не работает должным образом, нету зеленого окошка и ника сверху как на скриншоте. Хотя событие авторизации отдает success, переход на другое решение просьба не предлагать, прошу помочь!

Страница плагина на github: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Скриншот из другой игры: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MjKz.png

Comment: ИМХO, есть смысл информацию по ссылкам по возможности непосредственно вставить в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Версия Unity может играть роль. У меня стояла  версия Unity 2017.1.1f1,  но  после  перехода  на  версию Unity 5.6.4f1 все  заработало.